# Swift encode structs to data without having the full keys in the JSON

Tags: swift, nsdata

For protocol reasons, I have to convert my objects to `Data`. All methods I find online are using JSON for this, but since it's Swift-to-Swift, I am wondering whether there is a built-in mechanism provided for this.

Why I don't like JSON? It includes the full key names which, on scale, creates unnecessary overhead. Let me demonstrate what I mean:

```
struct Address: Codable {
    var city = ""
    var street = ""
}

struct Person: Codable {
    var name = ""
    var adresses = [Address]()
}

let addresses = [Address(city: "NY", street: "123"), Address(city: "LV", street: "456")]

let personA = Person(name: "A", adresses: addresses)

print(personA)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(personA) {
    print(encoded)
    
    let str = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)
    print(str) //{\"name\":\"A\",\"adresses\":[{\"street\":\"123\",\"city\":\"NY\"},{\"street\":\"456\",\"city\":\"LV\"}]}
    //it includes the complete key nnames in the JSON
}
```

Does Swift offer a more efficient way to do that in regards to size being transmitted? I know of Protocol Buffers but this seems a bit overkill here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using struct types I think your best bet is Codable. One way to get a smaller footprint is to apply a custom encoding (and also decoding) by encoding without keys

So add this to `Address`

```
extension Address {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(city)
        try container.encode(street)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        city = try container.decode(String.self)
        street = try container.decode(String.self)
    }
}
```

and similar for `Person`

```
extension Person {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(name)
        try container.encode(adresses)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        name = try container.decode(String.self)
        adresses = try container.decode([Address].self)
    }
}
```

encoding your example will give

> 33 bytes  <-- Down from 83 in my test
> ["A",[["NY","123"],["LV","456"]]]